# Create view from two tables while some row become column

Tags: sql

Hey I'm new to sql and I'm having a problem displaying data on my fpdf. I have these following tables:

**tbl_students**

```
studentID|fname |mname|lname   |grade  |section      |sy       |teacherid     
14-10546 |Aljhon|C    |Austria |Grade 2|St. Bernadeth|2018-2019|15-11100
12-23534 |Buklaw|K    |Buknoy  |Grade 2|St. Bernadeth|2018-2019|15-11100
```

**tbl_grades**

```
studentID|subjectID  |period        |sy       |final_grade
14-10546 |Science 101|First Grading |2018-2019|79.40       
14-10546 |Science 101|Second Grading|2018-2019|87.91
14-10546 |Science 101|Third Grading |2018-2019|0.00
14-10546 |Science 101|Fourth Grading|2018-2019|0.00
12-23534 |Science 101|First Grading |2018-2019|77.40       
12-23534 |Science 101|Second Grading|2018-2019|98.34        
12-23534 |Science 101|Third Grading |2018-2019|0.00
12-23534 |Science 101|Fourth Grading|2018-2019|0.00
```

I want to create view `view_all_grades` like this:

```
    studentID|fname |grade  |section      |sy       |FirstGrading|SecondGrading|ThirdGrading|FourthGrading    
    14-10546 |Aljhon|Grade 2|St. Bernadeth|2018-2019|79.40       |87.91        |0.00        |0.00            
    12-23534 |Buklaw|Grade 2|St. Bernadeth|2018-2019|77.40       |98.34        |0.00        |0.00
```

With what I tried so far, I'm receiving some error after executing the command :

> #1370 - execute command denied to user 'legend63'@'localhost' for routine 'tbl_grades.max'

```
CREATE view view_all_grades AS 
SELECT 
    tbl_students.studentID, 
    tbl_students.fname, 
    tbl_students.grade, 
    tbl_students.section, 
    tbl_students.sy, 
    tbl_grades.max(case when tbl_grades.period = 'First Grading' then tbl_grades.final_grade end) FirstGrading 
FROM 
    tbl_students 
    INNER JOIN tbl_grades ON tbl_students.studentID = tbl_grades.studentID
```

Comment: the following command outputs only one row:

CREATE view sample_view AS SELECT max(case when period = 'First Grading' then final_grade end) FirstGrading FROM tbl_grades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, a usual way to pivot data over a fixed number of columns is to use *conditional aggregation* :

```
CREATE view view_all_grades AS
SELECT
    st.studentID,
    st.fname,
    st.grade,
    st.section,
    st.sy,
    gr.subjectID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN gr.period = 'First Grading'  THEN gr.final_grade END) FirstGrading,
    MAX(CASE WHEN gr.period = 'Second Grading' THEN gr.final_grade END) SecondGrading,
    MAX(CASE WHEN gr.period = 'Third Grading'  THEN gr.final_grade END) ThirdGrading,
    MAX(CASE WHEN gr.period = 'Fourth Grading' THEN gr.final_grade END) FourthGrading
FROM
    tbl_students st
    INNER JOIN tbl_grades gr ON gr.studentID = st.studentID
GROUP BY
    st.studentID,
    st.fname,
    st.grade,
    st.section,
    st.sy,
    gr.subjectID
```

PS : from looking at your sample data, I came to suspect that you would need to include column `subjectID` in the view (else, what happens when there a student has grades in multiple subjects ?), hence I added it to the non-aggregated columns of the query.

Comment: st.final_grade should be gr.final_grade on your answer! anyway, thanks a lot!! It worked!!